# Transaction between several DAO layers?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, transactions, dao

As shown below, I am accessing a Service layer method inside of another DAO.
(Every DAO in the system is implemented using HibernateDAOSupport class)

I wanted to rollback the transaction when #1 or #2 (commented in the following code) is failed.
But when #2 throws an exception, #1 does not get rolled back and I can see the entries in the database.

```
@Transactional(readOnly=false, rollbackFor={DuplicateEmailException.class,DuplicateLoginIdException.class,IdentityException.class},propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void createUserProfile(UserProfile profile)
            throws DuplicateEmailException, DuplicateLoginIdException,
            IdentityException {

        // #1 create principal using Identity Service
        identityService.createPrincipal(profile.getSecurityPrincipal());

        try {
        // #2 save user profile using Hibernate Template
            getHibernateTemplate().save(profile);
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            throw new IdentityException("UseProfile create Error", e);
        }

}
```

Here is the signature for createPrincipal() method of'IdentityService'.

```
public void createPrincipal(Principal principal) throws DuplicateEmailException,DuplicateLoginIdException,IdentityException ;
```

There's no Transaction management configured in 'IdentityService'

What I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: The identityService.createPrincipal(...) method must be creating it's own transaction. How is its DAO configured?

Comment: That DAO has not configured for any transactions.(no Transactional annotation).

Comment: Only place I have used 'Transactional' annotation is in above DAO.

Answer (score 1):

Try `Propagation.REQUIRED`, instead of `Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW`

Answer (score 0):

During the calls `identityService.createPrincipal(profile.getSecurityPrincipal());` aren't you flushing the session ? (executing a query for example, with FlushMode.AUTO)